# How can some x and y coordinates be pulled out of a file where each line is in the form of (x1,y1) (x2, y2) with the c progamming language?

Tags: c, split, coordinates

I need to extract the various points from a line in a .txt file and assign them to variables that are already initialized.

```
//String would be something like (4,2) (1,5)
//I've tried to use scanf to use the keyboard and then from there I would move it over to
//fscanf and open the file.  So far I haven't been successful with scanf.  I tried this:  

int xCoord = 0;
int yCoord = 0;

printf("\nThis section grabs coords from user input\n");
printf("\n\nType in coordinates in the form of (x,y)\n");
scanf("%d %d", &xCoord, &yCoord);

printf("The x coordinate is: %d\nThe y coordinate is: %d\n", xCoord, yCoord);
```

//I'm not sure the best way to get just the numbers.  I have been able to get it to work if no
//parenthesis are used.  I've considered a tokenizer but I just wanted some suggestions.
//Thanks

Comment: `scanf(" (%d ,%d )", &xCoord, &yCoord);`

Comment: This worked wonderfilly.  Thank you.  Quick question though.  Why does this work instead of using something like a %*s%d ?  Also. I tried to move that over to fscanf and use a while loop.  while(fscanf("(%d,%d)",&xCoord, &yCoord) ==2) and it only works for the first iteration.  I have a file with 3 lines of test coords and only the first one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can use `scanf()`. The format string should be `" (%d ,%d ) (%d ,%d )"`. The spaces in the format string allow for any whitespace and the characters `(`, `)` and `,` match themselves.

Here is a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    printf("\nThis section grabs coords from user input\n");
    printf("\n\nType in coordinates in the form of (x1,y2) (x2,y2):\n");
    while (scanf(" (%d ,%d ) (%d ,%d )", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) == 4) {
        printf("x1=%d, y1=%d, x2=%d, y2=%d\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That worked and it makes sense.  I changed scanf to fscanf and it was able to successfully read in the file.  I got similar code right before this was posted but my code stopped in the while loop after one iteration and I'm not sure why.  I would post my code to compare too, but I'm new to stackoverflow and don't really know how to do that.  Thank you though.